# Keep getting weird php issues my code doesn't do anything at all super weird

Tags: php, html

Nothing happens with my code. data.txt doesn't change. my code is not activating I have no idea what to do please help me.

```
<?php

   $txt = "data.txt"; 
   if (isset($_POST['field1'])){  
      $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
      $txt=$_POST['field1'].PHP_EOL; 
      fwrite($fh,$txt); 
      fclose($fh); 
      $strrop="Application Submitted.";
      echo $strrop;
    };
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        type email here<br>
        <input type="text" name="field1"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" <img src="">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the errors. You never close the `isset`... or your never close the `if` depends how you look at it. Either way missing a `)`.

Comment: You have fixed the issue in your question pointed our by @user3783243. Did this resolve it? Is there another issue? What does "weird issue" mean? Do you get any errors, white screen? What actually happens? We can't debug by guessing, can you provide some info please?

Comment: white screen is what happens @James

Comment: That sounds likely to be a fatal error. Check your error logs for what exactly is wrong (or just find it in the code manually, this is more time consuming and harder) user3783243 pointed out an error but you just updated the question to fix it and never said whether that fixed your problem or not.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra semicolon in your code, in your close if bracket.

Try this:

```
    <?php

   $txt = "data.txt"; 
   if (isset($_POST['field1']){  
      $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
      $txt=$_POST['field1'].PHP_EOL; 
      fwrite($fh,$txt); 
      fclose($fh); 
      $strrop="Application Submitted.";
      echo $strrop;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;width:100%;">
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="field1">Type your email here</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        <img src="">
    </form>
</body>
```

EDIT: Also, use label tag for your inputs. And you let your last input open

Comment: I did not see that in the same way you didn't. You're asking for help and still being rude to people who wanna help you, amazing.